# WIF manually generate federationmetadata.xml

Tags: .net, wif, federated-identity

I am playing with windows identity foundation and I am trying to create an MVC.NET based Security Token Service and use it as the Single Sign On application.

My only problem is that I don't know how to generate the federationmetadata.xml file.

Is there any tool to generate this file manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a custom metadata generator that does what VS does when you create the STS project.
I had to use Reflection to call the code because as usual everything useful is internal in Microsoft's assemblies.

More about it [here](http://www.cosminonea.net/2009/12/wif-manually-generate.html)

Answer (score 0):

Right click the project and configure STS.

Comment: Do you mean that I can create an MVC.net web app and right click on it and turn it into an STS?
I don't see that option in the release version of WIF.

Comment: Have you installed the WIF redistributable and also the WIF SDK?

Comment: Also locate this file FedUtil.exe and use this if VS 2008 doesnt give you the option when you right click.....

Comment: see this link..it might help
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Geneva/thread/1c16046c-cf98-44f3-9235-48b02732b5e5

Answer (score 0):

http://stsmetadataeditor.codeplex.com/

This tool can be used modify an existing federationmetadata.xml

Load the VS2010 generated xml and change any attribute that you need to and save.

The saved version is compatible with the 2007-06 schema that VS2010 (WIF 3.5/ 4.0) use.

(would recommend backing up your original xml just in case )

I have done it many times and worked fine when I added STS reference to a Relying Party Website (VS2010 based)

Comment: there are many ways to do it now. this is an old question. another example of it is in identity server project http://identityserver.codeplex.com/ where Dominick generates the metadata on the fly.

Comment: This tool is riddled with bugs and there are exceptions happening everywhere. Although I appreciate the developers efforts, there's absolutely no point releasing this as it only wastes peoples time.